# Collision Detection returning a value derived from the image filename

Tags: java, collision-detection, filenames

I'm currently in the process of building a small Asteroids style game which is intended for use by the kids at a local junior school. The aim is to help them with their times-tables.

A randomly generated question is displayed on-screen, (example: 6 * ? = 12), and a number of star images with numbers on them are floating around, waiting to be be shot at! You control a ship and fly around hunting the correct answer.

Bullets collide with the stars and a test needs to be performed to see if the user has shot the correct answer or not.

The star's filenames are simply "1.png", "2.png" etc, and I have a small function to return the first character of the filename, and convert it to an int:

```
public rightAnswer() {

    String filename = "12.png";     //would be passed as parameters 
    int coefficient = 2;            //
    int answer = 24;                //

    char first = filename.charAt(0);
    char second = filename.charAt(1);       
    int target;

    if (second != '.') {    //dealing only with 1 or 2-digit numbers        

        String both = String.valueOf(first) + String.valueOf(second);           
        target = Integer.parseInt(both);
    }
    else {
        target = Character.digit(first, 10);
    }

    if (target * coefficient == answer) {
        System.out.println("Answer is correct! (target = " + target + ")");
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("Wrong! (target = " + target + ")");
    }
}
```

While writing I got struck by a problem. I can't figure out how to retrieve the filename of the collided star to pass it to the above test function.

edit:

taking a shot at Enno Shioji's solution, I've come to this:

```
//star map
Map<ImageEntity, Integer> star_number = new HashMap<ImageEntity, Integer>();

//later, while loading the images into the game...
for (int n = 0; n < 10; n++) {          // 10 loops

        stars[n] = new ImageEntity(this);
        String filename = (n+2) + ".png";   // 2- 12 range
        stars[n].load(filename);

        star_number.put(stars[n], n+2);
    }

//then later again, run when collision is detected between a bullet and a star...
public boolean correctAnswer(ImageEntity star, int expectedAnswer) {

    if (star_number.get(star) == expectedAnswer) 
        return true;

    else return false;
}
```

Is this looking right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would not try to grab the filename. Instead, you should keep track of which star corresponds to which number, in a Map.

```
// Do this wherever you have easy access to the file name
Map<Star,Integer> star_number = new HashMap<Star,Integer>();
star_number.put(star1,1);
star_number.put(star2,2);
etc...

//Then later...
boolean collided(Star star, Integer expectedAnswer){
    Integer answerGiven = star_number.get(star);
    return expectedAnswer.equals(answerGiven);
}
```

or, you could also keep track by defining the Star object as such:

```
class Star{
    Integer number;
    StarImage image;
    Star(StarImage image, Integer number){
        this.number = number;
        this.image = image;
}
// then later...
boolean collided(Star star, Integer expectedAnswer){
    return star.number.equals(expectedAnswer);
}
```

Hope this helps. Good luck with your project :)

Comment: I think I understand that - HashMaps add an assignment to each star? Then when a collision takes place the expected answer is the "target" value, answerGiven relates to the numbered assignment of the shot star, and if they're the same it returns true? I've not used HashMaps before; Will look into it right now! +1